# Call async code in an Action in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm calling a web service from some C# code. This code looks similar to this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var page = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";
  using (var response = await client.GetAsync(page))
  {
    using (var content = response.Content)
    {
      var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to execute this code within a utility method. From my understanding, an [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate is suited for this. I attempted to do this using the following:

```
Action action = delegate()
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var page = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    {
      using (var content = response.Content)
      {
        var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I wrap my web service code in an `Action` delegate, I receive a compile-time error that says:

```
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async anonymous method. Consider marking this anonymous method with the 'async' modifier.
```

My question is, how do I call async code in an Action? It looks like I can't. If I can't is there another way that I can pass a block of code to a utility method for execution? What does that look like?

Thank you!

Comment: `Action action = async delegate() ...`

Comment: `Func<Task> action = async () => {/*method body*/}` would also work. That way a Task is being returned that can be awaited by the caller of your method. As `Action` has the return type `void` I do not believe it can be awaited further up the call stack.

Comment: Use a static `HttpClient` instance; don't create a new one all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark your action as `async` just like you would any method, for example:

```
Action action = async delegate() 
    //snip
```

However, this is equivalent to an `async` `void` method which is not recommended. Instead you many consider using `Func<Task>` instead of action:

```
Func<Task> doStuff = async delegate()
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var page = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    {
      using (var content = response.Content)
      {
        var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can await the result:

```
await doStuff();
```

Comment: `HttpClient` shouldn't be created/disposed for each request.

Comment: @xxbbcc Well yes, but that's a different question

Comment: Yes, I know, I even hesitated posting the comment. I only did so because people will find your (otherwise good) sample and will just copy & paste without thinking.